# Difference bewteen AnimationTimer vs Transition

Tags: java, animation, javafx

Consider this code:

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.animation.Transition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class FrameTest extends Application
{
    private static final int SUBFRAMES = 1;
    private static final int FRAME_SAMPLE = 10;
    private long prevTime;
    private long frame;
    private ArrayDeque<Long> frameTimes = new ArrayDeque<>();
    private double fps;
    private int subframe;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }


    public void frameTick()
    {

        long time = System.nanoTime();
        if (prevTime != -1)
        {
            while (frameTimes.size() > FRAME_SAMPLE - 1)
                frameTimes.remove();
            frameTimes.add(time - prevTime);
            double fps = 0;
            for (long ftime : frameTimes)
                fps += ftime * 1e-9;
            fps = frameTimes.size() / fps;
            this.fps = fps;
            System.out.printf("%.9f\n", fps);
        }
        prevTime = time;

    }



    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        Transition trans = new Transition()
        {
            {
                setCycleCount(INDEFINITE);
                setCycleDuration(Duration.ONE);
            }

            @Override
            protected void interpolate(double frac)
            {
                frameTick();
            }
        };

        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer()
        {

            @Override
            public void handle(long now)
            {
                frameTick();
            }
        };

        //Comment out either one
        trans.play();
        //timer.start();
    }
}
```

It basically calculates the frame-rate of animation timer vs a transition.

When I run this FPS calculator with `javafx.animation.Transition` it spits out around 600 ~ 100000 fps (a large range). When I test it with AnimationTimer, it caps out nicely at around 60fps.

Just curious, what is the internal difference between these two approaches that cause such a disparage of results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the transition, you're not measuring actual frame rate; you're simply measuring the frequency at which `interpolate` is invoked. The scene will still only be rendered at a rate capped by the Prism rendering mechanism (by default this is capped at 60fps).

So if your `interpolate` method actually changed the scene graph, not all of those changes would actually be realized on the scene.

The `AnimationTimer`'s `handle()` method, by contrast, is actually invoked as part of the rendering of the scene: so it is guaranteed to be executed exactly once per frame.

Comment: thanks. Appreciate your explanation on `interpolate` vs `AnimationTimer`